# props are returned as string instead of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm currently implementing user authentication on my website, and I'm trying to restrict access to the login and signup pages if the user is logged in. To do so, I am implementing this `getServerSideProps` to redirect the user if they're logged in:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  if (context.req.cookies.user) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
    }
  }
  return {}
}
```

If I return an empty object (`{}`), next gives me this error:

```
Reason: Props must be returned as a plain object from getServerSideProps: `{ props: { ... } }` (received: `[object Array]`).
```

If instead of returning `{}`, I return

```js
{
  props: {}
}
```

the code works all right. Does anyone know why this is happening?

I'm using a custom `_app.jsx` file.

In the documentation, it's clearly mentioned that the props argument is optional:[image: Documentation]

Comment: Probably documentation is incorrect/not clear enough. Their own example that is similar to yours returns `{ props: {}}`. Perhaps what they meant that _contents_ of the `props` object is optional? You may want to create an issue on github.

Comment: All right, thanks for your help!

Comment: @tromgy While you're right that the documentation isn't clear, the issue is that one of `props`, `redirect` or `notFound` needs to be returned. In OP's case, since he doesn't want to redirect or return a 404, `props` must be returned. See the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70823242/1870780.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually intended. If you were using TypeScript, `return {}` would have thrown you error as `GetServerSidePropsResult` is defined like this [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/dd81d2c97e707355180938dc5f0f51d25f990f7c/packages/next/types/index.d.ts#L160-L163):

```
export type GetServerSidePropsResult<P> =
  | { props: P | Promise<P> }
  | { redirect: Redirect }
  | { notFound: true }
```

It means that any one of `props`, `redirect`, `notFound` needs to be present in the returned object. Perhaps you can create an issue at their [GitHub](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues) (and maybe a PR) to fix the documentation.

Comment: This looks right, the doc should've said it's `any of these properties` rather than `optional`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @tromgy, it was just the documentation that is unclear.